# How to Use An Instance of A Table Cell in Interface Builder?

Tags: interface-builder, nstableview

How do I use a copy of the same NSTableCellView in multiple columns in Interface Builder? In my table, there is only one cell identifier, which is a member of an NSTableCellView subclass, that is used throughout the entire table. Is this possible?

EDIT 1: This is my current project. The userInput NSTextField is wired up as an IBOutlet in the TextInputTableCellView class. My problem is that, when I try to add a TextInputTableCellView to the KeyColumn, I don't know where to begin.

[image: Xcode Interface Builder]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have attempted to just use Command + C (however that didn't work.) My primary problem is that there is a text field in the table cell view, which the subclass of NSTableCellView of which my cell is an instance, references as an IBOutlet. The problem is that, when I create the cell in the other column, I don't know what to do with the textField.

Comment: Why do you want to use one `NSTableCellView` in all columns?

Comment: I want to be able to have the same view / behavior in the cells of all columns. My thought was that the way to do this, was by using the same NSTableCellView. Is that not the correct way?

Comment: It depends on the behaviour and the number of columns.

Comment: @Willeke The behavior is defined in the TextInputTableCellView subclass, and there are two columns.

Comment: Can't you use the default table view and change the class of the table cell view in both columns? `NSTableCellView` already has a `textField` outlet.

Comment: The TextInputTableCellView supports text entry through an NSTextField, which NSTableCellView doesn't have. I just need to ensure that the Cell that uses the TextInputTableCellView has an NSTextField within it.

Comment: You're describing the default behaviour.

Comment: @Willeke There is no mechanism to enter text in the NSTableCellView class. How are you suggesting input is received in the default implementation?

Comment: How do you create the tableview? The template in IB contains `NSTextField`s.

Comment: @Willeke It contains one in the image because I added it manually. I am trying to figure out how to have a class that has the NSTextField in it automatically.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the IB template?

Comment: @Willeke Because I don't know how to do so without creating a new class for that cell (because the TextInputCellView subclass has an @IBOutlet).

Comment: The default `NSTableCellView` class has a `textField` outlet which is connected to the `NSTextField` in the template.

Comment: @Willeke From Apple's Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstablecellview the textField property is only for displaying text. The textField property of a default NSTableCellView does not provide a way for the user to edit the stringValue property.

Comment: Switch "Behavior" to "Editable" in IB or set `isEditable` in code. More info: [View based NSTableView editing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281045/view-based-nstableview-editing)

Comment: @Willeke Wow. I can't believe I didn't catch that. In any case, thanks for all of your help.